# C Defining an enum in one header file and using that enum as a function parameter in another file

Tags: c, enums

I have defined an enum in a header file, 
 global.h:

```
Typedef enum
{
    ELEMENT1,
    ELEMENT2,
    ELEMENT3
}e_element;
```

I have a second file using the enum as a function parameter.
file2.c

```
#include global.h
#include file2.h
Function(e_element x)
{
Body…
}
```

The prototype is in:
file2.h

```
Function(e_element x);
```

The compiler doesn’t know `e_element` in `file2.h`.  I have tried putting the `#include` for `global.h` in both `file2.c` and `file2.h`, but it still doesn’t see it. I would put the `enum` in `file2.h`, except that it is used by several other files, so if I move it the problem will just show up somewhere else.
How can I get the `file2.h` prototype to see `e_element`?

Comment: It's `typedef`, not `Typedef`. When I fix that, and add quotes around the header files in `#include`, your code compiles.

Comment: Fix your basic syntax errors, then see if you still have the problem.

Comment: Your code has a lot of typographic errors. I assume this is not your real code? Please post your real code, not some kind of pseudo-code. Or, OTOH, if this is really your code, you should first read a good textbook about C.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

global.h

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

typedef enum
{
    ELEMENT1,
    ELEMENT2,
    ELEMENT3
}e_element;

#endif
```

file2.h

```
#ifndef FILE_2_H
#define FILE_2_H

#include "global.h"
int test(e_element);

#endif
```

file2.c

```
#include "file2.h"

int test(e_element x)
{
    return x == ELEMENT1;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

edit:
`#ifndef` is conventionally used as a "header guard". It prevents a header file from being included multiple times by the preprocessor, which prevents things from being defined multiple times. It works by checking if a unique symbol has been defined before. If it has not, then it immediately defines it and then continues with the header file until `#endif`. If the symbol was already defined then it skips the guarded code completely, preventing multiple definitions. An example of multiple definitions would be if the same header file was included in a source and a header that the source also includes.

See [this link](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=header%20guards%20tutorial) for more information.

Comment: You should explain the purpose of all those `#ifndef`, maybe with also include a link to a tutorial on header guards.

Comment: Sure. I added some more info and a link.

Comment: Sorry. The code above was done in a hurry. The actual code says "typedef" with a small t (auto-correct), and the #include files are in quotes.

Comment: global.h
#ifndef SOURCES_GLOBAL_H_
#define SOURCES_GLOBAL_H_

//controller enum
typedef enum
{
 ELEMENT1,
ELEMENT2,
ELEMENT3
}e_controllers;
#endif /* SOURCES_GLOBAL_H_ */

file1.h // I get the error in this file
void setSequenceStatus(e_controllers controller, bool value);

file1.c
#include "file1.h"
#include "global.h"
void setSequenceStatus(e_controllers controller, bool value)
{
 if(controller == FF40_MMS_DSRC_CAS)
 {
  sequence_status_FF40 = value;
 }
}

Comment: From what you wrote it doesn't look like `file1.h` is including `global.h`. It must because it is using an enum from `globals.h`.

Comment: Thanks. In trying to solve this problem I have created test code which does just what you mentioned about including global.h in the file1.h file and it works, but there is something else going on in the actual software that I'm working on because even though i am including the .h file that contains the definition of the enum in the .h file that contains the prototype which uses the enum,  File1.h still gets "undefined type" for the enum. I have been having this problem for a while, and my solution has been to put the prototype in the .c file containing the function, but I'd rather use the .h

Comment: Is `globals.h` still being included in the `.c` file? If you remove it and only include `file1.h` does that make a difference?